# explicit specialization for function template c++

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates, explicit-specialization

```
template <typename T>
bool validate(const T& minimum, const T& maximum, const T& testValue) {
    return testValue >= minimum && testValue <= maximum;
}

template <> 
bool validate<const char&>(
    const char& minimum,
    const char& maximum,
    const char& testValue)
{
    char a = toupper(testValue);
    char b = toupper(minimum);
    char c = toupper(maximum);
    return a >= b && a <= c;
}
```

This is the function template, somehow in `main` when `validate` function is called, it never uses the second function(the one for `const char&`) even when the parameters are `char`. Can anyone see where my problem is?

Comment: Show us how you call it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type you specialized for - `const char&` does not match what `T` deduces as when you pass a `char` - it deduces to `char`!

(template type parameters can deduce to references only in presence of universal references)

So,

```
template <> 
bool validate<char> ...
```

---

Anyways, why are you not overloading instead?